# ReadStream and WriteStream to the same file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, race-condition

I create a `WriteStream` and a `ReadStream` for the same file.

I am testing code for persisting an object on disk.

```
# Code
g:(stream, cb)->
   stream.on("data", (chunk) -> chunks.push(chunk))
   stream.on("end", () -> cb(MyComplexObjectClass.decode(Buffer.concat(chunks)))

# Test
it "allows to persist MyComplexObject to disk", (done) ->
  MyComplexObject = ... # Initialization code
  _in = fs.createWriteStream("XXX")
  out = fs.createReadStream("XXX")
  _in.write(MyComplexObject.encode())
  _in.end()
  g(out, (x) ->
    # Validation of x here, should be MyComplexObject
    done()
  )
```

The test passes as is, three questions:

- I believe that there a race condition: when `end` is called on `_in`, the changes could potentially not be flushed to the file. How to reproduce the race condition in a test?
- Swapping `_in` and `out`'s declarations makes the program crash with   `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` although the file exists, why is that?
- Is there a better way to implement that (still using streams)?

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment but too long, given feedback I'll revise.

Is there some compelling reason not to use `JSON.stringify`? or something like:

```
#assumes custom myObj#toString
fs.writeFile "myObj.js", "module.exports = #{myObj.toString()}", (err) ->
  if err then throw err
  var importedObj = require 'myObj.js'
  assert.equal myObj.toString(), importedObj.toString()
```

I love streams as much as the next guy, even use RXJS to get them in the browser, but this seems like an odd use case.

## EDIT

So based on your feedback, at least to point one you make, the short answer is that you can't reliably test for a race condition *by definition*. If you could, it wouldn't be a race condition. Non-deterministic interleaving of instructions is assumed. As for the syntax error, every time I see something like that I check the output javascript, its almost always the cs being compiled in a way I didn't intend.

Comment: I use JSON.stringify actually in my implementation, this is not the point of the question:
1) How to prove the race condition and test for it?
2) Why swapping crashes?
3) I want to implement the test with the same file, still